# Parent/child type hinting in php constructor?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, php-5.2

Without getting into whether or not I should be using type hinting, can anyone tell me if there is a way to avoid PHP throwing an error when I pass a child class into a constructor that type hints for the parent? E.g.:

```
class Headed extends Image { ... }

class Dimension {
    function __construct(Image $image, $arg1, $arg2){ ... }
}
```

PHP gives me:

```
PHP Error 4096: Argument 1 passed to Dimension::__construct() must be an instance of Image, instance of Headed given
```

An object of type Headed would obviously also be an Image, since it is a child class, is there some way of phrasing my constructor so it gives the type hint but allows children?

*If this is due to me using PHP 5.2.5 instead of a more recent version than I'm sorry for bothering everyone.*

Comment: Test your code here: http://3v4l.org/. It will tell you if it is a version issue or not.

Comment: Perhaps if you had an interface, say "ImageInterface" where you have class Image implements ImageInterface, that way you hint instead with Image but with ImageInterface?

Comment: I used 3v4l.org like @JohnConde suggested and it works for me: http://3v4l.org/30dkZ (on all PHP 5.x versions)

Comment: This should not be the case. Type hints for classes explicitly also allow sub types of that class, that's one of the core ideas of OOP. Either you have found an obscure bug in an old version, or you are not testing this correctly (typo?).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments - I thought this was wrong but I wasn't sure. I went to try my full code in the site you suggested and discovered *facepalm* that Image extends Reference, Product extends Reference, and Headed extends Product... So I need to type hint for Reference (grandparent class). Sorry for the trouble and thank you all for helping me clear it up!

Comment: If working with namespaces, make sure the correct `use` path is provided. I had this problem too, only to realize I've been moving my classes around

Answer (score 0):

use `php 5.4.3`

i run this code

```
<?php

class Image {
public $a="s";
};

class Headed extends Image { };

class Dimension {
    function __construct(Image $image) 
    {
        var_dump($image);
    }
};

$h = new Headed;
$d = new Dimension($h);

?>
```

output:

```
object(Headed)#1 (1) { ["a"]=> string(1) "s" }
```